# GoLang Webserver - External Access - Port Issue - How to serve on port 9003 ( or any other)?

Tags: linux, webserver, port

How to serve on port 9003 ( or any other) ?

I have a Apache WebServer, running on a VPS ( ubuntu 16 ) . As standard, it runs on port 80 . If I try via browser :

```
http://104.XXX.YYY.237
```

It works just fine. ( I Have a full php/mysql app running on it )

.....

Now, I want to serve a public REST API, built with Golang, on port 9003 ( or whatever )

So I have on my main.go file

```
func main() {

    router := NewRouter()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9003", router))
}
```

When I try to access:

```
http://104.XXX.YYY.237:9003
```

I get no response at all.

...

I have a similar configuration running on my localhost, where I can successfully access thru terminal, curl, browser or ajax onto address like http://localhost:9003

So, not is wrong with my API.

...

I know very little about linux and server configuration, so, digging a bit about it, I could think that the problem may be the port 9003 ! To test that conclusion, I stopped the apache service, changed the API's port to 80, and !! BINGO !!! it worked ! I was able to access my API using my browser.

...

A little more digging and I found this (wonderful) linux comand :

netstat -vatn

which gave me the response: ( under my original config restored )

```
tcp6 0 0 :::9003 :::* LISTEN

tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN

tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN

tcp6 0 0 104.XXX.YYY.237:80 177.XX.YYY.243:4297 TIME_WAIT
```

I Am no linux expert, but, the first line says me that the 9003 port it is open and ready to be used, like the 80 and 22

But the last line says me that the server listens to 104.XXX.YYY.237:80.

So, I am short in one line. I conclude I should expect something like :

```
tcp6 0 0 104.XXX.YYY.237:9003 177.YY.XXX.243:4297 TIME_WAIT
```

So here my questions :

_ How to be able to provide external access to my API using my VPS's IP Addrress ( or later my domain ) using the given port ? _ Did I say something wrong about my conclusions ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I Managed to fix the Issue and allow externalconection straight to my API on port 9003 !

To achieve that, I edited the firewall rules on my VPS provider control panel!

Although, I really would like to learn how to do that by terminal !